# Why have all stars roughly the same order of surface temperature?

Tags: astrophysics, temperature, thermal-radiation, stars

Given that stars vary in volume over 10+ orders of magnitude, why are they roughly the same order of surface temperature (emitting much of their radiant energy in the visual range of the EM spectrum)?

Is there some sort of feedback mechanism which locks stars at surface temperatures on the order of blackbodies in the visual light range?

Comment: The temperatures of stars range over a full order of magnitude; do you consider that "roughly the same"?

Comment: Stars have almost arbitrarily low surface temperatures to 40,000+.  I would dispute the idea that they are roughly the same.   We mostly only notice the visible light emissions, though.

Comment: @probably_someone yes. given that volume varies over 10+ orders of magnitude

Comment: @BowlOfRed vast majority emit much in the visible light range

Comment: Something to do with the fact that volume is a 3D property, so differences in magnitude of radius are raised by three?

Comment: Get some perspective https://xkcd.com/2009/ What you are observing is whether the peak of blackbody radiation is above or below the visible spectrum: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/wien.html There is mystery about corona temperatures though https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/PT.3.3659

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assertion that they possess roughly the same temperature is not true. As pointed out by probably_someone, they vary over an order of magnitude, from dull red to blue-white. The apparent surface temperature of a star on the main sequence is set by its mass: the heavier it is, the faster it burns its fuel and the hotter its surface becomes.

If we look at stars on the main sequence, they all have a common feedback mechanism: if the star heats up, it expands slightly, the pressure and temperature in its core drop slightly, and the rate of energy production there goes down slightly. The star then contracts slightly, etc., etc. If the star cools off a bit, it contracts slightly and the pressure and temperature in the core go up slightly and the energy production rate goes up slightly. Then the star expands slightly, etc., etc.

For more information, see J. Craig Wheeler's (pop-sci) book on this topic.

Comment: temperature may vary over an order of magnitude but volume varies 10+ orders of magnitude, which is relatively much less

Comment: As manifested by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_star#Intrinsic_variable_stars

Comment: providing a source would improve this answer

Comment: The luminosity of a main sequence star is not *determined* by nuclear reactions, so that cannot be appealed to as the reason for a mass-dependence in the surface temperature. I think the key to any answer lies in terms of a discussion of opacities, in the interior and near the photosphere.

Comment: @robjeffries, why not post your comment as an answer- and enlarge upon your assertion that the luminosity of a main sequence star is not determined by nuclear reactions- this is difficult for me to grasp.

Comment: The latter is trivial. You will see from any set of evolutionary tracks that the luminosity of a star is set to within a small factor during the pre main sequence. Before nuclear fusion has begun. The luminosity is set by the rate at which energy can escape. The rate at which energy is generated is entirely dependent upon that.

Comment: hardly trivial for a non-professional ;-)